# problem with urlpatterns in django

Tags: django

why the url pattern like this:

```
api/actions/info/(?P<user_id>)/(?P<action_id>)/
```

does not recognize this url:

```
http://address/api/actions/info/3/4/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you don't actually match anything within the groups.

Use

```
^api/actions/info/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<action_id>\d+)/
```

Answer (score 3):

You've named your groups, but they don't actually *contain anything*.

```
api/actions/info/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<action_id>\d+)/
```